# Jaws of Death - The Merry Tiler More Show

Tags: knowledge, visual, lateral-thinking

Three categories are depicted by circles and tiles belonging to those categories should be placed inside (or otherwise outside). Tiles can belong to any number of categories (0 to 4). Two are given to you. Each of A to D has a unique solution from the six tiles below - what are they and why?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Venn diagram should likely be solved like this:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

Here the three circles represent:

> Top-left: **Things that can follow 'MEGA'**
>  - [Megadeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megadeth)
>  - [Megatron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megatron)
>  - [Mega Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sega_Genesis)
>  - [Megaton](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/megaton)
>
>  Top-right: **One-word movies**
>  - [Jaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaws_(film)) (1975)
>  - [Tron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron) (1982)
>  - [Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_(2011_film)) (2011)
>  - [Hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_(film)) (1991)
>
>  Bottom: **[Cricket terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms)**
>  - Ton, Drive, and Hook
>
>  'Duck' is a red herring for the cricket group, and 'Hertz' is a red herring for the 'Mega' group.

Comment: Nice, but there is also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Duck)

Comment: @cap Ah, interesting! Possibly less well known than the others, but yes - that would appear to be a viable alternative for position C... (or even B if you consider [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_(film)) also...) Hmmm...

Comment: *'In Brazil, sold as the "Cougar Boy"'*. Can you imagine the ads?